# JQuery and tabs - direct URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have a webpage with some tabs on it.
The links for the tabs looks like this:

```
<a class="tab active" href="#" data-tab="1">Some link text</a>
<a class="tab active" href="#" data-tab="2">Some link text</a>
<a class="tab active" href="#" data-tab="3">Some link text</a>
```

When the page load, all the tabs are active (css wise) - I know :)

And the tabs-code looks like this:

```
<div class="tab-content active" data-tab="1">
    Content of the tab
</div>
<div class="content" data-tab="2">
    Content of the tab
</div>
<div class="content" data-tab="3">
    Content of the tab
</div>
```

This works just fine, when I use it on the page.
But, what if I want to link to that specific page, but I want to start on tab number 1?

I realize, that if i had the id="1", I could probably just add a #1 to the url, but this is not an option with this code.

Anybody who can help?
Thank you.

Comment: What you are asking about is called **deep-linking** http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/2490-solution-for-deep-linking-tabs-f5.

Comment: Hi @evolutionxbox, I just posted a new comment - can you help me any further?

I found out how to get the #hash to the adress-line, but I'm not quite sure, how to move on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.
JQuery is not my strong suit.

I found the following code, which triggers the script:

```
$('body.player').find('tab').click(function(){
            var self = this;
            $('.playerLoaders').addClass('loading');
            $('.tab-content[data-tab="' + $(self).attr('data-tab') + '"]').siblings().removeClass('active');

            setTimeout(function() {

                    $('.loading-content').removeClass('loading');
                    $('.tab-content[data-tab="' + $(self).attr('data-tab') + '"]').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                    $(self).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');


            },1500);
        });
```